# What is the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{j=n}^{4n} {4n \choose j}\bigl(\frac{1}{4}\bigr)^{j} \bigl(\frac{3}{4}\bigr)^{4n-j}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the value of the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{j=n}^{4n} {4n \choose j}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{j} \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{4n-j}$$

First we take the limit of the summation from $0$ to $\infty$ then subtract the sum from $0$ to $n-1$. The value of the first sum is $1$. I can't determine the second sum with limit. How we find it?

Comment: Numerically it looks like it approaches a half.

Comment: We can regard such a sum as the probability that a binomial variable (the sum of $4n$ Bernoulli variables with $p=\frac{1}{4}$) lies in $[n,4n]$. The limit is given by applying the Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096636/how-to-show-i-pa-b-sum-j-aab-1ab-1-choose-j-pj1-pab-1-j):
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ \sum_{j\ =\ n}^{4n}{4n \choose j}
\pars{1 \over 4}^{j}\pars{3 \over 4}^{4n-j}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\
{\,{\rm B}\pars{1/4,n,3n + 1} \over \,{\rm B}\pars{n,3n + 1}}=\color{#66f}{\large\half}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\,{\rm B}}$'s are Beta Functions with
>   $\ds{\,{\rm B}\pars{x,y}=\,{\rm B}\pars{1,x,y}}$.

Note que
\begin{align}
\,{\rm B}\pars{p,n,3n + 1}&=\int_{0}^{p}t^{n - 1}\,\pars{1 - t}^{3n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&\sim\pars{1 \over 4}^{n - 1}\pars{3 \over 4}^{3n}\root{2}\sigma_{n}
\int_{- 1/\pars{4\root{2}\sigma_{n}}}^{\pars{p - 1/4}/\pars{\root{2}\sigma_{n}}}
\expo{-t^{2}}\,\dd t\,,\quad\sigma_{n}\sim{\root{3} \over 8}\,n^{-1/2}
\\[5mm]&\mbox{when}\quad n \gg 1
\end{align}

> The above limit is equivalent to
>   $$
> {\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{0}\expo{-t^{2}}\,\dd t}\over
>  \ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-t^{2}}\,\dd t}} = \half
> $$

Comment: I know the Beta function is denoted by $B(m,n)$ & I know the definition of it. But I don't know the function $B(p,m,n)$. You define, $B(1,x,y)=B(x,y)$. Well. But what does represent the function $B(p,m,n)$ for any value of $p$? Also it is not clear to me that in your 1st line how the summation transform to the Beta function? Please give me the general definition of $B(p,m,n)$.

Comment: @Panja.S. $\,{\rm B}\left(\, p,m,n\,\right)$ is the $\bf\tt\mbox{Incomplete Beta Function}$ which is reduced to the $\bf\tt\mbox{Beta Function}$ ( 'complete' ) $\,{\rm B}\left(\, m,n\,\right)$ when $p = 1$. The first line is the answer of the question given in the above link. By the way, I [have an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1096923/85343) to that question too.

Answer (score 4):

We can regard such a sum as the probability that a binomial variable $B$, given by the sum of $4n$ independent Bernoulli variables $X_i$ with $p=\frac{1}{4}$, lies in the interval $[n,4n]$. Since the expected value of $B$ is $n$, the [strong law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) gives that the value of the limit is just $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

The second term of the asymptotics obviously depends on the [skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) of $X_i$.

Comment: +1. I like very much the type of arguments you show here.